# Creating custom posts in wordpress images not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've built a custom wordpress theme for a client and as part of the theme I have created custom posts that means they will be able to add a repeated copy/image slide to a part of the website, without needing to come to me. Most of this is taken from an amazing tutorial on pluralsight however this is the only bit thats not working.

The copy appears fine however I'm having an issue with the images not recognising the source.

My functions.php code...

```
---------  Custom Classes Post Type --------
*/

function create_post_type()
{
    register_post_type(
        'glasseye_classes',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Classes'),
                'singular_name' => __('Class')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => 'title'
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_type');

// define prefix 
$prefix = 'ge_';


$meta_box = array(

    'id' => 'classes-meta-box',
    'title' => 'Add New Class Listing',
    'page' => 'glasseye_classes',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Title',
            'descr' => 'Enter the copy for your phone',
            'id' => $prefix . 'phone_copy',
            'type' => 'text'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Phone image URL',
            'descr' => 'Please paste the full URL for the phone gif. You can find this in the Media Libary',
            'id' => $prefix . 'phone_image',
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Box Theme',
            'descr' => 'This sets the color scheme for the class box.  Please look at Classes page to determine the appropriate theme for your new listing',
            'id' => $prefix . 'theme',
            'class' => $prefix . 'theme',
            'type' => 'theme_colors',
            'options' => array(
                array('color' => 'Pink'),
                array('color' => 'Purple'),
                array('color' => 'Teal'),
                array('color' => 'Green')
            )
        )

    ) //fields array


); // meta_box aray    

add_action('admin_menu', 'glasseye_add_box');

// Add meta box

function glasseye_add_box()
{
    global $meta_box;

    add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'glasseye_show_box', $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}


function glasseye_show_box()
{
    global $meta_box, $post;

    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="glasseye_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

    echo '<table class="form-table">';

    foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        // get current post meta data
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

        echo '<tr>',
            '<th style="width:20%"><label for="',
            $field['id'],
            '">',
            $field['name'],
            '</label></th>',
            '<td>';
        switch ($field['type']) {
            case 'text':
                echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />', '<br />', $field['descr'];
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>', '<br />', $field['descr'];
                break;
            case 'select':
                echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<option ', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
                break;
            case 'radio':
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
                }
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
                break;
            case 'theme_colors':
                echo $field['descr'], '<br><br>';
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<label>', $option['color'], ' <input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['color'], '" id="', $field['id'] . '_' . strtolower($option['color']), '"class="', $field['class'], '"', $meta == $option['color'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' /></label><br>';
                }
        }
        echo     '</td><td>',
            '</td></tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'glasseye_save_data');

// Save data from meta box
function glasseye_save_data($post_id)
{
    global $meta_box;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['glasseye_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}
```

Where it is referenced in my index.php...

```
        <?php
        $args = array('post_type' => 'glasseye_classes', 'posts_per_page' => 10);
        $loop = new WP_Query($args);

        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            the_content();

            $meta_box_fields = $meta_box['fields'];

            // returns the key for the Name field for each Class
            $phone_copy_key = $meta_box_fields[0]['id'];
            $phone_copy_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $phone_copy_key, true);

            $image_key = $meta_box_fields[2]['id'];
            $image_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $image, true);

            $class_skill_key = $meta_box_fields[3]['id'];
            $class_skill_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $class_skill_key, true);

            $class_length_key = $meta_box_fields[4]['id'];
            $class_length_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $class_length_key, true);

            $class_description_key = $meta_box_fields[5]['id'];
            $class_description_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $class_description_key, true);

            $class_theme_key = $meta_box_fields[6]['id'];
            $class_theme_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $class_theme_key, true);

        ?>


            <h1><?php echo $phone_copy_value ?></h1>
            <div class="phone-animation">
                <img class="phone-animation-xlarge phone-five-animation-xlarge" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/circle.png" alt="red circle" />
                <img class="phone-animation-large phone-five-animation-large" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/circle.png" alt="red circle" />
                <img class="phone-animation-medium phone-five-animation-medium" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/circle.png" alt="red circle" />
                <img class="phone-animation-small phone-five-animation-small" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/circle.png" alt="red circle" />
                <div class="phone-image-container">
                    <img src="<?php echo $phone_value ?>" class="instructor-headshot" alt="<?php echo $class_instructor_value ?> Headshot">

                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
```

what the image tag looks like in dev tools...

```
<div class="phone-image-container">
                    <img src(unknown) class="instructor-headshot" alt=" Headshot">
   </div>
```

Comment: You don't have `$phone_value` defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had missed off defining the phone_value (pointed out by @Howard E), and also missed some configuration with the image_key.

Updated code...

```
     $phone_image_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $phone_image_key, true);
```

I also needed to add in some extra bits to get my lazy loading working

```
<img data-src="<?php echo $phone_image_value ?>" class="lazy-load" alt="<?php echo $phone_copy_value ?>">
```

Works as expected now.